# Android Studio - Want 1 APK, but not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build one APK to debug 2 versions of the same program.

Android Studio makes split/sliced apks now, just because.

Using my Google-fu, I found out that disabling Instant Run will create 1 apk.

But when I disable Instant Run, nothing works. I keep getting the "Too many errors" crap.

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myApp:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.    at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)  at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)   at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54) at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)   at 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34) at 
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236) at 
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228) at 
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)    at 
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106) at 
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)  at 
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)

All internal errors. Seriously?! What must I do to make it build one apk?

Comment: You should show your app level build.gradle. Can you post it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> just change your applicationId from the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio gradle - `applicationIdSuffix`

```
   android {  
       ...  
       buildTypes {  
         release {...}  
         debug {  
           applicationIdSuffix '.debug' 
         }  
       }  
    }
```

For more Info go [Here](http://techblog.weddingwire.com/blog/posts/gradle-build-variants-for-the-common-dev-part-1-build-types)

Comment: Now shows `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myApp:processDevDebugGoogleServices'.` I have updated `google-json` to include the "package_name" to have `myApp.dev`, as well as copying/pasting it into src/dev/google-services.json.